# How do Change swf file dimension in html....?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, size

I just built a flex applcation with AS3 only.. the generated swf will expand as much as browser's window..I wish to reduce the dimension of swf file...any ideas?? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify your swf dimensions eg:

```
[SWF(width="640", height="480")]
```

If you're viewing it directly in your browser, you should embed your swf inside an html document and specify the dimensions of your swf.
If this is for a public facing website, I'd recommend using [SwfObject.js](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). Or if you aren't comfortable with Javascript you can use the object tag:

```
  <object width="640" height="480">
    <param name="movie" value="your_file.swf">
    <embed id="embed" src="your_file.swf" width="640" height="480"></embed>
  </object>
```

Comment: your object tag is not working in my case...swf still expand as much as it can...and [SWF(width="640", height="480")] won't scale the swf file...all I need is 1.3 scaleX and scaleY on swf +1 though